# Order list of objects by using a property of IEnumerable

Tags: c#

I'm trying to sort a list and I'm getting this error:

Failed to compare two elements in the array. At least one object must implement IComparable.

here is the code

```
public class Program
{
    public  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            var list = new List<A>
            {
                new A("a"),
                new A("b"),
            };

            var asc = list.OrderBy(_ => _.Titles);
            
            Console.WriteLine(asc.First().Titles.First());

            var desc = list.OrderByDescending(_ => _.Titles);
        
            Console.WriteLine(desc.First().Titles.First());
    }

    public class A : IComparable<A>
    {
        public A(string value)
        {
            Titles = new List<String>
            { value};
        }

        public IEnumerable<string> Titles { get; set; }

        public int CompareTo([AllowNull] A other)
        {
            return this.Titles.First().CompareTo(other.Titles.First());
        }
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/pRYA75

How to implement IComparable in this case?

Comment: Well, what do you want the IComparable implementation to do? How should it compare two collections of strings?

Comment: just compare the first element from property Titles

Comment: How about `list.OrderBy((el1, el2) => el1.Titles.First().CompareTo(el2.Titles.First());` ?

Comment: You've specified how to compare two instances of `A`, but then you tell `OrderBy` to sort based on `A`'s `Title` property, and to ignore the code you wrote telling it how to compare two instances of `A`. If you want to use the implementation of `IComparable<A>` you wrote, you need to use `list.OrderBy(x => x)`

Comment: @canton7, it needs to be specific by Titles, I am having multiple properties and they might be ordered independently

Comment: @SasGabriel Either 1) Use the implementation of `IComparable<A>` you wrote, in which case using `.OrderBy(x => x)` will call this, or 2) Throw away the implementation of `IComparable<A>`, and add that logic to the `OrderBy` call, e.g. `OrderBy(x => x.Titles.First())`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
var asc = list.OrderBy(_ => _.Titles);
...
var desc = list.OrderByDescending(_ => _.Titles);
```

to

```
var asc = list.OrderBy(_ => _);
...
var desc = list.OrderByDescending(_ => _);
```

The `_` in your lambdas are instances of `A`.  `A` is what can be compared to another `A`.  `A.Titles` is ultimately what you use in `A` to compare, but it itself does NOT implement `IComparable`.

---

**Edit:** From the comments, I see strong confusion in you as to what IComparable actually does.  So I'm taking your Class A and heavily commenting the `CompareTo` method:

```
// Class A implements IComparable<A>.  So it's expecting 
// a CompareTo method that compares two instances of A
// to decide which is greater than or less than the other.
public class A : IComparable<A>
{
    public A(string value)
    {
        Titles = new List<String>
        { value};
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Titles { get; set; }

    // When you do SomeA > SomeB, or SomeA < SomeB, and so on,
    // Decide which comes before the other based on the first
    // title registered in each.
    //
    // So, if SomeA.Titles is "Title1" and "Title2"
    // and if SomeB.Titles is "Label1" and "Label2"
    // then SomeA > SomeB evaluates to "true" because 
    // "Title1" comes later in alphabetical ordering 
    // than "Label1".
    //
    // But you don't have to actually write out 
    // SomeA.Titles.First() > SomeB.Titles.First() because that
    // logic is already taken care of in A.CompareTo.  Just
    // Write SomeA > SomeB.
    // 
    // And because .OrderBy() relies on comparisons such as 
    // >, <, =, and so on, it uses 'CompareTo' under the hood.
    // So you can just do SomeListOfA.OrderBy(item => item)
    // and it just works. 
    public int CompareTo([AllowNull] A other)
    {
        // Below is equivalent to:
        // return this.Titles.First() < other.Titles.First() ? -1
        //    : this.Titles.Firsst() > other.Titles.First() ? 1
        //    : 0; 
        //
        // In things that want to know order, such as .OrderBy(), 
        // they use the output -1, 1, or 0 to learn if an object
        // is less than, greater than, or equal to another object,
        // respectively.
        return this.Titles.First().CompareTo(other.Titles.First());
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not implement IComparable but what to do in case I want to order by other properties independent of Titles, let's say I have a property public long Id {get;set;}, and when I want to order by Id then I can just use OrderBy(_ => _.Id) and it works

Comment: You can order by such an `Id` becasue it is of type `long`, alias for [System.Int64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int64?view=net-5.0), which already implements IComparable.

Comment: I agree, but I'm looking how to sort them by Titles which is a List<string> and doesn't know IComparable, but I want to implement it somehow, if it is possible

Comment: @SasGabriel That's been answered several times in the comments. Either implement `IComparable<A>` for `A`, which tells it how to correctly compare two `List<string>`s **and use this**, or use `.OrderBy(x => x.Titles.First())`